# MySQL: Парочка вопросов по InnoDB

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста один нюанс, в документации написано, что InnoDB не поддерживает полнотекстовой поиск. Я так понимаю, что это имеется в виду отсутствие поддержки запросов типа LIKE %..%, а как на счет обычного условия LIKE? Т.е. могу ли я в базу InnoDB отправить запрос типа:

```
SELECT `article` FROM `articles` WHERE `tag` LIKE 'sometag'
```

Возможно пример не очень удачный, заранее извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIKE](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4225) имеет мало общего с полнотекстовым поиском. Речь идет о Fulltext и функции match...against

Ссылка - на описание бага. Но смысл тот же: тут вовсю используют %

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Просто я оказывается никогда не пользовался fulltext и match O_o